# Why am I getting a red wire for my out?

Tags: verilog, hardware, modelsim

I am attempting to create an output that goes on for a certain amount of time an then goes low for a certain amount of time and my out simply won't simulate.

Attached is my code, test bench, and simulation.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You never assert `rst` so the state machine never goes to a known state from which it can switch into other states like you want.

Comment: how does one assert in verilog ?

Comment: In your testbench, don't just set `rst` to 0. Set it to 1 initially, then after some time change it to 0. (if this doesn't work, then you might need to actually change it 0-1-0 to be sure of generating a posedge on rst)

Comment: Hmm I did this and nothing changed :(

Comment: Did you try setting `rst` to 0, then 1, then 0?

Comment: Because if your simulator is strictly simulating the Verilog per Verilog rules, it needs a positive edge on `rst` for reset to happen.

Comment: You could also just use an initial block to start with `state` set to 0000.

Comment: @help: Note that when you post a screengrab of your code that we would have to type it all out to test it or post it in our answers. Please post the code as text and use the `{}` code formatting button instead. Check that everything looks right in the preview before posting.

Comment: @ThePhoton: *"it needs a positive edge on `rst` for reset to happen."* Not sure why you think that. The process will be evaluated whenever any of the events listed in the sensitivity list occurs. So if `rst` is asserted during a clock edge, the reset will occur.

Comment: @DaveTweed, well yes, that's another option, but OP didn't share their modified code and I didn't want to go into that much detail in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

My first time doing verilog here is the code

The mistakes were as follows:

1. Your **count**, wasn't initiated, so it was adding uknown with a +1 which returned an unknown; i also took the liberty initiated **state** as well.
2. It did not know what to do when the **state** was **3'b000**, you had the following covered 1,2,4; (you could use the "default" in case statement in verilog and set it to a known state? )

Suggestions :

- I separated out the reset from the case logic, makes more sense to me that way
- Might want to add a reset toggle to your test bench, within the first 10 ns or so as was suggested

the code is as follows

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps


module clocksignal(
    input clk,
    input rst,
    output out
    );

    reg [5:0] count =5'b00000;
    reg [2:0] state =3'b000;
    reg w_output;

    always @(posedge clk, posedge rst) begin
        if (rst == 1) begin
            state <= 3'b000;
            count <= 5'b00000;
            end
        else
            case(state)
                3'b000 : 
                    state <= 3'b001;
                3'b001 : 
                    state <= 3'b010;
                3'b010 : 
                    if (count < 29) 
                        count  <= count + 1;
                    else if (count ==29 ) begin
                        state <=3'b100;
                        w_output <= 1;
                        count <= 0;  
                    end                     
                3'b100 : 
                    if (count < 42) begin
                        count <= count + 1;
                        w_output = 1;
                    end 
                    else if (count == 42) begin
                        count <= 0;
                        w_output <= 0;
                        state <= 3'b001;
                    end
             endcase
    end

    assign out = w_output;
endmodule
```

[image: Simulation]

Comment: You should also include out and w_output in the reset statement to avoid the red lines. w_output should also be assigned an initialization value before reset just as you did with count and state. Posting the test bench you used might also be helpful to the OP unless you used the same one that OP posted